# Is there any disadvantage to using the same bundle identifier for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios

I finished my iOS version of my app `com.example.testapp`, and now I want to build the Android version. Is there any disadvantage to doing this? The advantage in my mind is organization, and the bundle identifier will be same for iOS and Android in the "Installations" class in my Parse.com database.

Comment: The IDs won't be identical - the iOS bundle ID has a prefix. Modulo that, no disadvantage.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDs won't be exactly identical - the iOS bundle ID has a prefix. Modulo that, no disadvantage that I can think of.